# Knockout.js : Mapping to existing table, adds Multiple Entries

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I have a table in HTML and would like to define some knockout.js observables on them. When i click on the createTrack function, existing contents of table are once again added, would like to add a new entry for track. Help needed to fix this problem.

Note : I don want to dynamically fetch content using JSON, as it affects SEO/other reasons.

Link to Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ATDJp/1/

View Model Code

```
(function () {
    var tracks = ko.utils.parseHtmlFragment('#tracks-table');

    // represent a single track item
    var Track = function (TrackNo, TrackTitle, TrackLength) {
        this.TrackNo = ko.observable(TrackNo);
        this.TrackTitle = ko.observable(TrackTitle);
        this.TrackLength = ko.observable(TrackLength);
    };

    var TracksViewModel = function (tracks) {
        var self = this;

        // All track
        self.tracks = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(tracks, function (track) {
            return new Track(track.TrackNo, track.TrackTitle, track.TrackLength);
        }));

        // Add a new Track on click of new button
        self.createTrack = function () {
            // Add a new Track
            self.tracks.push({ TrackNo: "", TrackTitle: "", TrackLength: "" });
        };
    }

    // check data from local table

   // var tracks = ko.utils.parseJson(JSON.stringify(jQuery('#tracks-table').tableToJSON()));

    // bind a new instance of our view model to the page
    var TracksViewModel = new TracksViewModel(tracks || []);
    ko.applyBindings(TracksViewModel);
})();
```

Comment: Please also post your view! A working JSFiddle would be even better...

Comment: You should also add your html code to the question.

Comment: done :-) But add function is not working :(

Comment: @Sandro HTML code in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you're really not trying to work with dynamic data.  Why don't you switch out knockout for this task and use jQuery.  There was also an HTML error (non ending TD).

http://jsfiddle.net/ATDJp/3/

```
$('#btnaddnewtrack').on('click', function() {
        $('#tracks-table tr:last').after('<tr><td>3</td><td>track3</td><td>4:30</td></tr>'); 
});
```

Comment: Tat works !! Oops, jQuery approach will break the model altogether. After this i want to have double click to edit on existing tracks.To do this in jQuery i would end up in writing lot of code.

Comment: Well you're mixing static and dynamic data. If you want to edit static data, then what are you actually editing. It's editing the display. Could you create a static page for SEO That is quietly linked on the page and then populate your view model with actual dynamic data.  Then you would have a flexible and dynamic page that users interact with and a static page that crawlers interact with.

Comment: @Mike, I have a similar problem. It's not static. The data list is retrieved from DB on page load. Then I want to add / remove items from the list. Each time an item is added or removed, Httprequest is sent to server to update DB. I don't see the point of retrieving the data on page load through Ajax, when this can be done server side.